# Grabbing a list of all Public and Private channels within Slack

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, slack, slack-api

I'm in the process of writing a python bot that does a number of things for me, one of those things is to display every channel within my workspace along with the member count. This isn't that complex and as of now I'm able to do this but only for public channels. Having a read through the [conversations.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list) API documentation it points to using a solution like:

```
result = slack_client.conversations_list(exclude_archived=1, types="public_channel, private_channel")
```

Now, when attempting to use the above it will call, but it'll only grab public, it does however exclude archived channels as I expect. I've tried different combos and have gotten nowhere. Is this something no longer supported or am I missing something obvious?

Additionally, we're on the plus plan of Slack.

Comment: What scopes does your token have? it'll require the `groups:read` scope to get a list of private channels. It's also not possible to pull private channels that the token owner (bot or user) isn't a member of.

Comment: Hey @ColmDoyle I do have the documented scopes that are required, I don't believe scope is the issue here but perhaps what you're touching on regarding membership issues. The issue I have is I would be fine having the bot job all channels but I need to be able to detect the channels ID for it to join it, it can unless it's a member, catch 22 here. What would you suggest is the best method for the bot to be able to read private channels in this situation? If the option isn't there then is this a problem enterprise would resolve?

Comment: Yes, users (bot or human) cannot join channels, they must be invited by an existing member of the channel.

What you probably need is the [Discovery API](https://slack.com/intl/en-gb/help/articles/360002079527-A-guide-to-Slack%E2%80%99s-Discovery-APIs)

Comment: That's interesting @ColmDoyle we are in talks to move to ent grid but the cost isn't cheap, if there is no way of doing so it leaves us with blocking private channels or spending another million. I might chase Slack on our end to see if these really are our best options and let others decide.

Comment: What's the use case for having the bot in _all_ channels? Is it just that you want a list of the private channels and that's it?

Comment: We're looking to manage our channels, specifically archiving inactive channels depending on time of last message as well as amount of members in them - also we want to delete 1 month old messages due to the area we work in / sec reasons - a few others but those are the main ones